# UITableView renders badly after updating cells

Tags: uitableview, core-data, rendering

In my app I have UITableView & table data can be updated from remote after user request. I use Core Data & NSFetchedResultsController and when changes took place, `-controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` is called:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
    atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
    newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

All works correctly, except one thing. Sometimes, after reloading the first row, it is displayed without border (border suddenly disappears). What can be wrong?

P.S.: For updating data I create new `NSManagedObjectContext` in background and manage `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`. When notification comes, `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` is performed on main thread - so updates are made from main thread also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you've got a problem in:

```
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

… where you provide a cell of the wrong type or size for index zero.

Comment: But why the cells displayed correctly for the first time? Code is the same - only label texts differs!

Comment: Hmm. I've made some changes in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code to setup cell's background only during creation and not each time it's reloaded - and now all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be an issue with core data.

Try calling

```
 [cell.backgroundView setNeedsDisplay];
```

in order to update the cell. If it does not work, try calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the `tableView`.